# For each loop in Asp.net Gridview not working properly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` with `Checkbox control` and I want to get the selected checkbox(es) but when I tried to iterate the `Gridview` using `For Each Loop` the data being retrieved is duplicated. I really don't know how to fix it. I've google same problem or approach to this and I got the same code so what I'm missing here? Here is my code:

```
  For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim chkRow As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox)
            If chkRow.Checked Then
                Dim name As String = row.Cells(1).Text
                Response.Write(name)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Here is my `aspx` code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-bordered" runat="server" 
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Laboratory Name" HeaderText="Laboratory Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the information, it sounds as though you are rebinding the gridview on postback.

Put a check for postback in the code where you are databinding.

`If Not IsPostBack() Then
     Me.GridView1.DataBind()
End If`

Comment: Where should I locate that sir? On Page_Load?

Comment: What is the datasource for the gridview? Are you setting it in the code behind? If so, you should place the call to this method where the Me.Gridview1.DataBind() is in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

if your filling the grid on page load then use

```
If Not IsPostBack() Then 
GridView1.DataBind()  <if your you are populating data through class just add it>
or
populate(param1, param2,...)
End If
```

this will surely solve your problem